# php returns null passing variable value

Tags: php

The problem with code below is variable sp1. When replacing sp1 into "where" clause with a city name already existing in database, everything works well. But when i send startPoli1 variable from my app, php returns nothing. Logcat shows that startPoli1 is being sent every time. Any suggestion;

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("......","......","......" );
$database = "......";
$ok = mysql_select_db($database, $con);
mysql_set_charset("UTF8",$con); 


$us1 = $_POST['username1'];
$sp1 = $_POST['startPoli1'];
$fp1 = $_POST['finalPoli1'];
$w1 = $_POST['weight1'];
$em1 = $_POST['eidosmetaf1'];
$dD1 = $_POST['depDate1'];
$dT1 = $_POST['depTime1'];


$sql = mysql_query( "  SELECT `username1`,`startPoli1`, `finalPoli1`, `eidosmetaf1`, `weight1` , `depDate1` , `depTime1`, `tilefono1` 
 FROM customer ,registration1 
 where   (customer.startPoli1 = 'sp1')  and   
 (customer.username1 = registration1.username )");

    if($sql === FALSE) 
    { 
    die(mysql_error()); 
    }
    $results = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
   $results[] = array(
        'username1' => $row['username1'],
        'startPoli1' => $row['startPoli1'],
        'finalPoli1' => $row['finalPoli1'],
        'eidosmetaf1' => $row['eidosmetaf1'],
        'weight1' => $row['weight1'],
        'depDate1' => $row['depDate1'],
        'depTime1' => $row['depTime1'],
        'tilefono1' => $row['tilefono1']
         );
         }
    echo json_encode(array('select_itin_results' =>$results));
    mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

Comment: in your code you're not even using the sent values for anything. is that on purpose or did you post the wrong code?

Comment: **WARNING** You're very vulnerable to SQL Injection. You should [take some measures to secure your app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Note: You should be using prepared statements to build your sql queries and never pass user data directly into your queries without sanitizing it.

Comment: So, in other words, my friend, you have 2 options: 1. make it work with a framework; 2. Use prepared statements :)

Comment: @AresDraguna #1 option isn't guranteed.

Comment: @itachi I know... I've stopped using plain PHP from bottom up since 2010 :)

Comment: P.S: I recommend YII - best framework there is!!! (**Y**es **I**t **I**s)

Comment: @AresDraguna Just because the letters form that statement doesn't necessarily mean it's the best framework. You should choose your framework best suited for your application.

Comment: The best framework there is affirmation belongs to me :) in my opinion that IS the best framework... beats Zend by a mile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `$` before the variable name. ie `where   (customer.startPoli1 = '$sp1')` so the final query is using the string "sp1" instead of the value of the variable `$sp1`

After you understand that, learn about [**the proper way**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) of making sql queries to avoid people messing with your database with sql injection

Comment: An then you have a great SQL injection ready code using deprecated `mysql_` functions... ;)

Comment: First make it work, then make it secure, he clearly is starting to code

Comment: old habits are hard to get rid off. better to start off with good ones.

Comment: I see your point, linked to "how to avoid sql injection in php"

Answer (score 3):

### You're not using the value of the variable $sp1

Instead, you're using the string `'sp1'`, the dollar symbol`$` is missing in your clause:

```
where (customer.startPoli1 = 'sp1')
```

Should be changed to:

```
where (customer.startPoli1 = '$sp1')
```

### But be ware of the threat that comes along with the solution:

You are vulnerable to [sql-injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), which you can avoid by stop using `mysql_*` functions, since they're [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) and instead you should begin to use [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). You can see how by checking other [useful post about the matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).